# Issue in dyplr group_by

Tags: r, group-by, syntax-error

I'm trying to group using `dyplr`, but it's a error with the code:

```
mtcars %>%
    group_by(mtcars$gear) %>% 
        summarise(cor = cor(mtcars$mpg, mtcars$hp))

cor
1 -0.7761684
```

Comment: You should erase all `mtcars$` 's.

Comment: Try `mtcars %>% group_by(gear) %>% dplyr::summarise(cor = cor(mpg, hp))`